# How do I go about fixing cross-browser issues with my MailChimp HTML newsletter?

Tags: html, html-email, html-table, mailchimp

I am experiencing a lot of browser inconstancies with my HTML newsletter. Are there any glaring issues you are able to diagnose just by looking through the code? For example, the newsletter has a really long height to - far beyond the content's height. This is just one specific issue.

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <!-- Facebook sharing information tags -->
    <meta property="og:title" content="*|MC:SUBJECT|*" />

    <title>*|MC:SUBJECT|*</title>

    <style type="text/css">

        /* Client-specific Styles */
        #outlook a{padding:0;} /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" button. */
        body{width:100% !important;} .ReadMsgBody{width:100%;} .ExternalClass{width:100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
        body{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;} /* Prevent Webkit platforms from changing default text sizes. */

        /* Reset Styles */
        body{margin:0; padding:0;}
        img{border:0; height:auto; line-height:100%; outline:none; text-decoration:none;}
        table td{border-collapse:collapse;}
        #backgroundTable{height:100% !important; margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important;}

        body, #backgroundTable{
             background-color:#FAFAFA;
             font-family: Arial;
        }
        #templateContainer{
             border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
        }
        p {
            color: #5a5a5a;
        }
        a {
            color: #8b8b8b;
        }
        h1, .h1{
            color:#202020;
            display:block;
            font-family:Arial;
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight:bold;
            line-height:100%;
            margin-top:0;
            margin-right:0;
            margin-bottom:10px;
            margin-left:0;
            text-align:left;
        }

        h2, .h2{
            color:#202020;
            display:block;
            font-family:Arial;
            font-size:22px;
            font-weight:bold;
            line-height:100%;
            margin-top:0;
            margin-right:0;
            margin-bottom:10px;
            margin-left:0;
            text-align:left;
        }

        h3, .h3{
            color:#202020;
            display:block;
            font-family:Arial;
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight:normal;
            line-height:100%;
            margin-top:0;
            margin-right:0;
            margin-bottom:10px;
            margin-left:0;
             text-align:left;
        }
        h4, .h4{
             color:#202020;
            display:block;
             font-family:Arial;
             font-size:22px;
             font-weight:bold;
             line-height:100%;
            margin-top:0;
            margin-right:0;
            margin-bottom:10px;
            margin-left:0;
             text-align:left;
        }
        #templatePreheader{
             background-color:#FAFAFA;
        }
        .preheaderContent div{
             color:#505050;
             font-family:Arial;
             font-size:10px;
             line-height:100%;
             text-align:left;
        }
        .preheaderContent div a:link, .preheaderContent div a:visited, /* Yahoo! Mail Override */ .preheaderContent div a .yshortcuts /* Yahoo! Mail Override */{
             color:#336699;
             font-weight:normal;
             text-decoration:underline;
        }
        #templateHeader{
             background-color:#FFFFFF;
             border-bottom:0;
        }
        .headerContent{
             color:#202020;
             font-family:Arial;
             font-size:34px;
             font-weight:bold;
             line-height:100%;
             padding:0;
             text-align:center;
             vertical-align:middle;
        }
        .headerContent a:link, .headerContent a:visited, /* Yahoo! Mail Override */ .headerContent a .yshortcuts /* Yahoo! Mail Override */{
             color:#336699;
             font-weight:normal;
             text-decoration:underline;
        }
        #headerImage{
            height:auto;
            max-width:600px;
        }
        #templateContainer, .bodyContent{
             background-color:#FFFFFF;
        }
        .bodyContent div{
             color:#505050;
             font-family:Arial;
             font-size:14px;
             line-height:150%;
             text-align:left;
        }
        .bodyContent div a:link, .bodyContent div a:visited, /* Yahoo! Mail Override */ .bodyContent div a .yshortcuts /* Yahoo! Mail Override */{
             color:#336699;
             font-weight:normal;
             text-decoration:underline;
        }
        .bodyContent img{
            display:inline;
            height:auto;
        }
        .leftColumnContent{
             background-color:#FFFFFF;
        }

        .leftColumnContent div{
             color:#505050;
             font-family:Arial;
             font-size:14px;
             line-height:150%;
             text-align:left;
        }
        .leftColumnContent div a:link, .leftColumnContent div a:visited, /* Yahoo! Mail Override */ .leftColumnContent div a .yshortcuts /* Yahoo! Mail Override */{
             color:#336699;
             font-weight:normal;
             text-decoration:underline;
        }
        .leftColumnContent img{
            display:inline;
            height:auto;
        }

        .rightColumnContent{
             background-color:#FFFFFF;
        }
        .rightColumnContent div{
             color:#505050;
             font-family:Arial;
             font-size:14px;
             line-height:150%;
             text-align:left;
        }
        .rightColumnContent div a:link, .rightColumnContent div a:visited, /* Yahoo! Mail Override */ .rightColumnContent div a .yshortcuts /* Yahoo! Mail Override */{
             color:#336699;
             font-weight:normal;
             text-decoration:underline;
        }
        .rightColumnContent img{
            display:inline;
            height:auto;
        }

        #templateFooter{
             background-color:#FFFFFF;
             border-top:0;
        }
        .footerContent div{
             color:#707070;
             font-family:Arial;
             font-size:12px;
             line-height:125%;
             text-align:left;
        }
        .footerContent div a:link, .footerContent div a:visited, /* Yahoo! Mail Override */ .footerContent div a .yshortcuts /* Yahoo! Mail Override */{
             color:#336699;
             font-weight:normal;
             text-decoration:underline;
        }
        .footerContent img{
            display:inline;
        }
        #social{
             background-color:#FAFAFA;
             border:0;
        }
        #social div{
             text-align:center;
        }
        #utility{
             background-color:#FFFFFF;
             border:0;
        }

        #utility div{
             text-align:center;
        }

        #monkeyRewards img{
            max-width:190px;
        }
        ol {
            padding-left: 20px;
        }
        li {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .letter-from-editor {
            float: left;
            display: inline;
            color: #24ae04;
            font-size: 22px;
            margin-left: 40px;
        }
        .publication-date {
            float: right;
            margin-top: 0;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            margin-right: 20px;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        td.bodyContent {
            padding: 25px;
        }
        .support {
            text-align: center;
            color: #24ae04;
            font-size: 22px;
            margin: 15px 0;
        }
        .continue-reading {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .footer-links {
            font-size: 12px;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .the-footer {
            width: 600px;
            text-align: right;
            margin:20px 0 50px 0;
        }
        .all-footer-links {
            margin-top: 65px; 
            border-top: 1px solid #e8e8e8; 
            border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8; 
            width: 600px;
            padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
            text-align: right;
            font-size: 12px; 
            color:#e8e8e8;"
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0">
    <center>

        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="backgroundTable">
            <tr> 
                <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <!-- // Begin Template Preheader \\ -->
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="templatePreheader">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" class="preheaderContent">

                                <!-- // Begin Module: Standard Preheader \ -->
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <!-- *|IFNOT:ARCHIVE_PAGE|* -->
                                        <td valign="top" style="background-color: #000000;color: #FFFFFF;">
                                            <div mc:edit="header_links" style="text-align:center;">
                                                Having trouble viewing this email? <a target="_blank" href="*|ARCHIVE|*" target="_blank">View it in your browser</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <!-- *|END:IF|* -->
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <!-- // End Module: Standard Preheader \ -->

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!-- // End Template Preheader \\ --> 


                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="backgroundTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                            <!-- // Begin Template Preheader \\ -->
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="templatePreheader" style="border-bottom:1px solid #e8e8e8;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" class="preheaderContent">
                                    <!-- // Begin Module: Standard Preheader \ -->
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                        <tr>
                                        <!-- <td valign="top">
                                        <div mc:edit="std_preheader_content">
                                        Use this area to offer a short teaser of your email's content. Text here will show in the preview area of some email clients.
                                        </div>
                                        </td> -->
                                        <!-- *|IFNOT:ARCHIVE_PAGE|* -->
                                        <td valign="top" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                                            <div mc:edit="message" style="text-align:left; margin:30px auto; width:600px;">
                                                <h1 style="color:#3db0df;">example's Weekly Newsletter</h1>
                                                <p mc:edit="top-header-message" style="width:440px;display:inline;font-size:12px;line-height:140%;">Each week we'll keep you informed about features, products, and service<br>updates. Be sure to go to our <a target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com">website</a> and follow us on <a target="_blank" href="http://www.twitter.com/example">twitter</a> for more<br>frequent news in between.</p>
                                                <img mc:edit="logo-main" style="float:right;margin-top:-55px;" src="logo.png" />
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <!-- *|END:IF|* -->
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <!-- // End Module: Standard Preheader \ -->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!-- // End Template Preheader \\ -->


                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="margin-top:50px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                <h1 mc:edit="from-the-editor" class="letter-from-editor">A letter from the editor</h1>
                                <p mc:edit="publication-date" class="publication-date">March 28, 2012</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>


                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateContainer">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                <!-- // Begin Template Header \\ -->
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateHeader">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="headerContent">

                                            <!-- // Begin Module: Standard Header Image \\ -->
                                            <img src="header.png" style="max-width:600px;" id="headerImage campaign-icon" mc:label="header_image" mc:edit="header_image" mc:allowdesigner mc:allowtext />
                                            <!-- // End Module: Standard Header Image \\ -->

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <!-- // End Template Header \\ -->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                <!-- // Begin Template Body \\ -->
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateBody">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="3" valign="top" class="bodyContent">

                                            <!-- // Begin Module: Standard Content \\ -->
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="100%">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td valign="top">
                                                        <div mc:edit="std_content00">
                                                            <h2 class="h2" style="color: #3db0df;">5 Ways To Be Happy Right Now</h2>
                                                            <p>Down in the dumps. The Blues. The doldrums. No matter what you call it - sometimes, even if you are the happiest person around, you start to feel like crud.</p>
                                                            <p>This week there seems to be a crazy amount of negative info swirling around - whether it's deadly tornados or horrible rhetoric as the Republican primaries heat up (especially negative for women on this one, but I'll try to not get political!) And, I guess some of this finally got to me...so I tried everything I could to get myself out of my funk.</p>

                                                            <h3 class="h3" style="color: #3db0df;"><em>Here were the 5 things that worked the best:</em></h3>
                                                            <ol>
                                                                <li>I did a <strong>20 minute workout</strong> (mostly going for brisk walks) right after I woke up in the morning - before I started my day. No matter what happened that day, i knew i had done something good for myself. That made me happy.</li>
                                                                <li>I made sure to <strong>drink a lot of water</strong>. Dehydration is very fatiguing on the body - this fatigue can quickly turn to crankiness. So drink up!</li>
                                                                <li>I <strong>made a playlist</strong> of 'pump up' tunes. Played them on blast and repeat. I made sure to choose songs that had great memories attached and got my heart rate going. It's amazing how much dancing around your house (or apartment) totally uninhibited, can put a smile on your face!</li>
                                                                <li>Made a point to <strong>hang out with a friend that really makes me feel good</strong> - is a lot of energy and has a great sense of humor. Laughter is always the best medicine for the blues.</li>
                                                                <li><strong>Read example</strong>, of course! There is so much great stuff here, that i can always find something to cheer me up. ;) (some of those great finds are below!)</li>
                                                                <p>Hope you are having an excellent week!</p>
                                                                <p>Be well,</p>
                                                                <p>Erin</p>
                                                            </ol>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            <!-- // End Module: Standard Content \\ -->
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <!-- // End Template Body \\ -->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <br>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" width="275" class="leftColumnContent">
                    <!-- // Begin Module: Top Image with Content \\ -->
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="400">
                        <tr mc:repeatable>
                            <td valign="top" style="border:1px solid #e8e8e8;">
                                <img src="bulb.png" mc:label="image" mc:edit="post1" />
                                <div mc:edit="tiwc300_content00" style="padding:20px;">
                                   <h4 class="h4" style="color:#3db0df;">3 Tips for Finding Positivity in an Endlessly Negative Workplace</h4>
                                   <p>Today’s society is riddled with negativity. Maybe it’s like this for every generation...</p>
                                   <a target="_blank" href="" style="text-decoration:none;color:#3db0df;">Continue Reading >></a>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </8r>
                    </table>
                    <!-- // End Module: Top Image with Content \\ -->
                </td>

                <td width="44"></td>

                <td valign="top" width="275" class="rightColumnContent">

                    <!-- // Begin Module: Top Image with Content \\ -->
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="400">
                        <tr mc:repeatable>
                            <td valign="top" style="border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;">
                                <img src="dog.png" mc:label="image" mc:edit="post2"/>
                                <div mc:edit="post2" style="padding:20px;">
                                   <h4 class="h4" style="color:#3db0df;">What to Do When You Don’t Feel Like Doing Anything</h4>
                                   <p>Where in your life is stress a noticeable concern? Maybe you get stressed out from work, family responsibilities...</p>
                                   <a target="_blank" href="" style="text-decoration:none;color:#3db0df;">Continue Reading >></a>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!-- // End Module: Top Image with Content \\ -->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table>
            <h1 mc:edit="sponsor" class="support">example is pleased to support</h1>
        </table>

        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="600" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
            <div style="width:600px;background-color:#FFFFFF;padding:10px 0;margin-bottom:70px;">
                <img mc:edit="advertisement" src="ad.png" />
            </div>
        </table>

        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="600" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border-top:1px solid #e8e8e8;">
            <div class="all-footer-links" style="margin-right:20px;">
                <div style="float:left;margin:-127px 0 0 0;">
                    <img mc:edit="footer-logo" src="logo-footer.png"/>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-right:10px;">
                    <a target="_blank" class="footer-links" href="http://www.example.com/blog/motivation/">Motivation</a> | 
                    <a target="_blank" class="footer-links" href="http://www.example.com/blog/productivity/">Productivity</a> | 
                    <a target="_blank" class="footer-links" href="http://www.example.com/blog/health/">Health</a> | 
                    <a target="_blank" class="footer-links" href="http://www.example.com/blog/self-improvement/">Self Improvement</a> | 
                    <a target="_blank" class="footer-links" href="http://www.example.com/blog/contact/">Contact Us</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div mc:edit="footer-links" class="the-footer">
                <p style="float:left;font-size:10px;margin-left:10px;">Copyright &copy; 2012 example</p>
                <div style="margin-right:10px;">
                    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/example"><img mc:edit="facebook" src="facebook.png" /></a>
                    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.twitter.com/example"><img mc:edit="twitter" src="twitter.png" /></a>
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/102257056998496075187"><img mc:edit="googleplus" src="googleplus.png" /></a>
                    <a target="_blank" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/example/LYVv/"><img mc:edit="rss" src="rss.png" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </table>
    </center>
</body>
```

Comment: CSS in email generally will not work. Your best bet is to pretend it's 1997 and code like that.

Comment: @Cfreak , whats so special about 1997 ?

Comment: @tusar the point was that using HTML3 with minimal styles is the way to fix the problem. I agree with your answer below.

Comment: @Cfreak , that's a pleasure you liked it. Thank you so much ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS classes are ignored by email clients. If you are using standalone clients (like Outlook Express) to view your emails, `div`s will also not be working (`float:left` will be ignored).

I suggest you to change your HTML page like -

- Drop everything outside the `<body>...</body>`
- Use `<table>` instead of `<div>`
- Dont use `<style>` tags to define style-classes, or `.css` file to load styles. Instead use *inline css* like `style="...."` with the `<td>` / `<table>` containers.
  Hope this helps you in email template designing.

This way you can make your email cross-browser compatible for all websites (like gmail.com) and stand-alone clients (like outlook express).

Comment: Also one more info : `<center>` is deprecated for years. Use `text-align:center` in the parent container's `style` attribute to center align the inner content.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Change Height to auto

`#backgroundTable{height:auto; margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important;}`

2 - Add `text-aligh:center` to TD

`<td valign="top" style="text-align:center;background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                                        <div mc:edit="message" style="text-align:left; margin:30px auto; width:600px;">
                                            <h1 style="color:#3db0df;">example's Weekly Newsletter</h1>
                                            <p mc:edit="top-header-message" style="width:440px;display:inline;font-size:12px;line-height:140%;">Each week we'll keep you informed about features, products, and service<br>updates. Be sure to go to our <a target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com">website</a> and follow us on <a target="_blank" href="http://www.twitter.com/example">twitter</a> for more<br>frequent news in between.</p>
                                            <img mc:edit="logo-main" style="float:right;margin-top:-55px;" src="logo.png" />
                                        </div>
                                    </td>`

3 - Change Height to auto

`<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="auto" width="600"  style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
    <div style="width:600px;background-color:#FFFFFF;padding:10px 0;margin-bottom:70px;">
        <img mc:edit="advertisement" src="ad.png" />
    </div>
</table>`